# Any Mercurial extension to grep for newly checked in code (not having "console.log")?

Tags: mercurial, grep, version-control, dvcs

Is there any Mercurial extension that can grep for "console.log" that might have been accidentally left over as debugging code?

Right now this is what I am doing:

```
1) hg out ssh://....
```

the above is to see what is the first committed revision in my local repo, say, the smallest revision is 3456

```
2) hg diff -r 3455 | grep "^+" | grep "console\.log"
```

The number `3455` is `3456 - 1`.  the first grep is to see newly added code.  the second one is for console.log

This method can tell that I have "console.log" in the new code, but won't say what file it is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're in need of a commit hook.  Try putting something like this into your .hg/hgrc (or ~/.hgrc if you want it global):

```
[hooks]
pretxncommit = sh -c 'if hg log -p -r $HG_NODE | grep -q '^\+.*console\.log' ; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi'
```

That will abort your commits if they would be adding a line that contains console.log.  Your commit message will be saved in .hg/last-message.txt.

See http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html for more details.